# How to disable lonpress in a UIWebview on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebview to display local .html.  I want to disable longpress in this view.  How would I go about executing this?

Here is what fixed it:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I had tried something similar, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this for pages you don't control by calling:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = \"none\";"];
```

from the `UIWebViewDelegate` method:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```